# Updating tags on user's portal item via API

Tags: arcgis-portal

I'm using the extract data widget to create extract files.  It writes these files to the logged in portal user's content.

I want to tag the items that were just created but I can't find anywhere in the api that lets me do that.

Example of what I want to do:

```
var myUrl = 'somevalue';  // I know this value at runtime, so not a problem.
var myItemId = 'someOtherValue'; // Ditto.

var thisPortal = new arcgisPortal.Portal(myurl);
thisPortal.signIn().then(function (loggedInUser) {
    loggedInUser.getItem(myItemId).then(function(theItem) {
         // I want to add a tag to the item so I know it's ok to automatically toss it a day later.
         theItem.tags[theItem.tags.length] = 'Delete in One Day';
        // I want to write the item back to the portal.
        // And I cannot find any documentation on this step!
    })
});
```

I don't want to have to trust the users to clean up after themselves.   I have a concern that they will clog up the disk with extract files that they will never look at again and never throw away again.

I can ask the users to mark whether the extract should be held temporarily or permanently before the extract files are created (and default to temporarily!)  If I then tag the extract files accordingly, I can have an automated program run every evening and toss out the expired ones.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var myUrl = 'somevalue';  // I know this value at runtime, so not a problem.
var myItemId = 'someOtherValue'; // Ditto.



var thisPortal = new arcgisPortal.Portal(myurl);
thisPortal.signIn().then(function (loggedInUser) {

    var theToken = loggedInUser.credential.token;
    loggedInUser.getItem(myItemId).then(function(theItem) {
         // I want to add a tag to the item so I know it's ok to automatically toss it a day later.
         // then I want to write the item back to the portal.
         // I could not find any way to do this in the 3.20 javascript api, so I'm using the restful api.
         var tagsCsv = '';
         for (var i = 0; i < theItem.tags.length; i++) {

             tagsCsv = tagsCsv + theItem.tags[i] + ',';
         }
         tagsCsv = tagsCsv + 'Delete in One Day';

         // I could not find any documentation for the restful api to do this either, but I could observe via the

         // browser debugger what the portal did when I manually added a tag to the portal item.

         var updateUrl = '{portalUrl}sharing/rest/content/users/{userId}/items/{itemId}/update';
         updateUrl = updateUrl.replace('{portalUrl}',myUrl);
         updateUrl = updateUrl.replace('{userId}',loggedInUser.username);
         updateUrl = updateUrl.replace('{itemId}', theItem.id);
         xhr.post(updateUrl, {

            data: {

                tags: tagsCsv,
                clearEmptyFields: 'true',
                id: theItem.id,
                f: 'json',

                token: theToken

            }

         }).then(function(data) {  // officially a success

                  // inspect and take whatever action you deem fit.

             },

             function(error) {   // officially a failure

                  // inspect and take whatever action you deem fit.

             },

             function(evt) {  // status notification, works depending on the browser version.

                  // inspect and take whatever action you deem fit.

             });

    });
});
```

I had to transpose this by hand, hopefully it's syntactically correct.  If not, post the mistakes and I'll edit it to match.

Comment: Haven't you tested it yet? It is OK to accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Yes, I tested the original code.  But the code is on a machine that's not connected to the internet and I can't just cut and paste it here.  So I had to manually read the code on one machine and type it into this site.  It's possible there is a typo that I didn't catch.